# Search for row where email contains only the X character

Tags: sql-server, regex

I want to search for rows whose `column email` has only the `X` character.

For example, if the **email** is `XXXX`, it should fetch the row but if the email is `XXX@XXX.COM` it should not be fetched.

I have tried something like this, but it is returning me all emails having the character `X` in it:

```
select *
from STUDENTS
where EMAIL like '%[X+]%';
```

Any idea what is wrong with my query?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27569954/7124761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
select *
from STUDENTS
where LEN(EMAIL) > 0 AND LEN(REPLACE(EMAIL,'X','')) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE PATINDEX('%[^X]%', Email)=0
```

Only X means no other characters than X.

To handle `NULL`s and empty strings you should consider additional conditions. See demo below:

```
WITH STUDENTS AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('XXXX'),('XXX@XXX.COM'),(NULL),('')) T(Email)
)
SELECT *
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^X]%', Email)=0 AND LEN(Email)>0
```

Comment: I don't think patindex bettter than regex

Answer (score 0):

This will find all rows where email only contain 1 or more X and no other characters.

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE Email not like '%[^X]%' and Email <> ''
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this solves the OP's problem?